# A result in multivariable statistics

Tags: linear-algebra, statistics, multivariable-calculus

I'm having problems proving the following result:
$$\sum ^{n}_{i=1}(\underline{X_{i}} - \underline{\mu})(\underline{X_{i}} - \underline{\mu})^{T} = \sum^{n}_{i=1}(\underline{X_{i}}-\overline{\underline{X}})(\underline{X_{i}}-\overline{\underline{X}})^{T}+n(\overline{\underline{X}}-\underline{\mu})(\overline{\underline{X}}-\underline{\mu})^{T}$$
Where $\underline{X_{i}}$ is the notation for a vector.
This is what I tried to do:
$$\sum^{n}_{i=1}\left[(\underline{X_{i}})-\overline{\underline{X}})(\underline{X_{i}}-\overline{\underline{X}})^{T} + (\underline{X_{i}}-\overline{\underline{X}})(\overline{\underline{X}}-\underline{\mu})^{T}+(\overline{\underline{X}}-\underline{\mu})(\underline{X_{i}}-\overline{\underline{X}})^{T}+(\overline{\underline{X}}-\underline{\mu})(\overline{\underline{X}}-\underline{\mu})^{T}\right]$$
$$\sum^{n}_{i=1}\left[(\underline{X_{i}}-\overline{\underline{X}})(\underline{X_{i}}-\overline{\underline{X}})^{T} + (\underline{X_{i}}-\overline{\underline{X}})(\overline{\underline{X}}-\underline{\mu})^{T}+(\overline{\underline{X}}-\underline{\mu})(\underline{X_{i}}-\overline{\underline{X}})^{T}\right]+n(\overline{\underline{X}}-\underline{\mu})(\overline{\underline{X}}-\underline{\mu})^{T}$$
But I don't understand why $(\underline{X_{i}}-\overline{\underline{X}})(\overline{\underline{X}}-\underline{\mu})^{T}$ apparently equals 0.
Any help would be appreciated thank you!

Comment: Ignoring the underbars, I doubt $(X_i - \bar X)(\bar X - \mu)^T)$ is zero, but the sum over $i$ is.

Comment: That makes sense thank you so much!